# PostgreSQL: How to generate edge list from an array of tags?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data which looks like the following:

```
id, tags
1,{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
2,{'A', 'C', 'D'}
3,{'A'}
4,{'B', 'D'}
5,{'A', 'D'}
6,{'D'}
7,{'D'}
```

My goal is to transform it into an edge list ( or co-occurrence) table as shown below:

```
tag1,tag2,count
'A', 'A', 1
'A', 'B', 1
'A', 'c', 2
'A', 'D', 3
'B', 'C', 1
'B', 'D', 2
'C', 'D', 2
'D', 'D', 2
```

Notice the first & last line in the above table (`'A', 'A', 1` & `'D', 'D', 2`) is because A appears on its own only 1 where as D appears twice - so they are self-connected.

How can I do this efficiently using PostgreSQL 9.3? I have over 350K tags & 1.9 million documents.

Sample data:

```
create table tags( 
id int
,tagList text[]
);

insert into tags values (1,ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']);
insert into tags values (2,ARRAY['A', 'C', 'D']);
insert into tags values (3,ARRAY['A']);
insert into tags values (4,ARRAY['B', 'D']);
insert into tags values (5,ARRAY['A', 'D']);
insert into tags values (6,ARRAY['D']);
insert into tags values (7,ARRAY['D']);
```

What I've tried:

```
select a.tag, b.tag, count(*)
from
(select id, unnest(taglist) as tag
from  tags
) as a
inner join 
(select id, unnest(taglist) as tag
from  tags
) as b
on a.id = b.id and a.tag !=b.tag
group by a.tag, b.tag
order by a.tag, b.tag
```

Which produces:

```
tag tag count
A   B   1
A   C   2
A   D   3
B   A   1
B   C   1
B   D   2
C   A   2
C   B   1
C   D   2
D   A   3
D   B   2
D   C   2
```

What's missing in the above table is: It considers `A->B` & `B->A` as independent - I don't want that to happen ( I think the term here is, I'm working with an undirected graph) and the other thing is: It is missing self-connected vertices. i.e., 'A<->A' & 'D<->D' - I suppose that is because of the `a.tag!=b.tag` condition in the join statement.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/03ebe/2)

PS: I have the data set in a long form too i.e, one tag on each row so each document (id) could be spread across many rows.

Comment: Edited my answer to cover an error case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/03ebe/24)

```
with s as (
    select
        id,
        unnest(taglist) as tag,
        array_length(taglist, 1) as l
    from  tags
)
select a.tag as tag1, b.tag as tag2, count(*)
from
    s a
    inner join
    s b on
        a.id = b.id
        and
        (
            a.tag < b.tag
            or
            (
                a.tag = b.tag
                and
                1 = all(array[a.l, b.l])
            )
        )
group by a.tag, b.tag
order by a.tag, b.tag
;
 tag1 | tag2 | count 
------+------+-------
 A    | A    |     1
 A    | B    |     1
 A    | C    |     2
 A    | D    |     3
 B    | C    |     1
 B    | D    |     2
 C    | D    |     2
 D    | D    |     2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the same result *except for* the self-connected edges count by simply changing `a.tag != b.tag` to `a.tag < b.tag`.  In effect, A gets compared to B, C, D; B get's compared to C and D; C get's compared to D; and no tag gets compared to itself.

The complete query would look like:

```
select a.tag, b.tag, count(*)
from
(select id, unnest(taglist) as tag from  tags) as a
inner join 
(select id, unnest(taglist) as tag from  tags) as b
on a.id = b.id and a.tag < b.tag
group by a.tag, b.tag
order by a.tag, b.tag
```